# Adding solines to acumatica using rest Api

Tags: rest, curl, acumatica

Am trying to create a sales order in acumatica using rest API with more than one soline but am able to create only one soline, below see my code

I would like to create one sales order with all cart items as solines for that particular sales  order in acumatica.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $row) {
        if ($row['qty'] != 0) {

            $product = $row['product'];
            echo $product.
            "<br>";
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxxxxxx.com/myinstance/entity/PLUS/17.200.001/SalesOrder",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => 1,
                CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $temp_data,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n \"OrderType\" : {value : \"SO\" } ,\r\n \"CustomerID\" : {value : \"C000000002\" },\r\n \"webItems\" : {value : \"$product\" },\r\n\"webQty\" : {value : \"1\" },\r\n\"WebTaxCat\" : {value : \"TAXABLE\" },\r\n}",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("cache-control: no-cache", "content-type: application/json", "postman-token: 5248821b-91e9-5800-bd9c-b4c9775c6c5a"),
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);
            if ($err) {
                echo "cURL Error #:".$err;
            } else {

                echo $response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you add what you mean when you say "but am able to create only one soline"? Does a second one break? Do you not know how to code two requests?

Comment: If I code two requests I will get two sales orders but for my case I just need only one sales order with the line items as sales order lines in acumatica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code you seems to have created your own endpoint or extended the default endpoint.
Though looking at the structure of the body that you are passing through the detail information seems to be on the same level as the top level entity.

If you created your own endpoint from scratch, I would recommend that you take a look at the Sales Order entity from default endpoint and its Details sub entity.

As normally, you should have a details object inside of the Sales Order node that can contain an array of details information.

If I was using the default endpoint I could pass the following JSON body to the address :

- localhost/191u03/entity/Default/18.200.001/SalesOrder

```
{
    "CustomerID": {"value": "ABARTENDE"},
    "Details": 
    [
        {
            "InventoryID": {"value": "AACOMPUT01"},
            "OrderQty": {"value": 5}
        },
        {
            "InventoryID": {"value": "AALEGO500"},
            "OrderQty": {"value": 50}
        }
    ]
}
```

This will create a Sales Order with 2 So Lines.
Though if you want to add more line to an existing order then you should only need to mention the key fields of the top level entity and then the details information that you would want to add.

In the case of the Sales Order, the key fields are the OrderType and the OrderNbr.

If you have the time, I would recommend that you take a look at the Acumatica help website section about working with the contract based API: https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(5))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=1c767ad9-da6d-4047-bc93-6970ad469504